# Connect Workbench to MySQL installed on Windows AWS

Tags: mysql, windows, amazon-web-services, mysql-workbench

I have window AWS and MYSQL installed using IIS installation features. Everything works fine. I am trying to connect MYSQL on my windows AWS via workbench from my laptop. I used instance address in host and 3306 as port but it doesn't connect. any help

Answer (score 0):

Check here for help:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ConnectToInstance.html

Make sure you check the Security Group, your database may be allowing only localhost connections and you need to add your ip to that security group.

Comment: you didn't understand my question. I have installed MySQL via IIS and not from Amazon RDS.